# Run an existing Yii2 App

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to run an existing yii app. In my app I have :

```
-backend 
-frontend 
-common 
-console 
-.bowerrc 
-.gitignore 
-.htaccess 
-composer.json 
-composer.lock 
-prod.htaccess
```

Comment: What do you mean with "run an app"?

Comment: @Bfcm i want to run an existing project

Comment: Where is the vendor dir? I am on my phone but it looks like your missing directories and files. There should be a vendor dir and Yii file. You have to run Yii init before doing anything on the advance template

Answer (score 0):

With the installation guide for the advanced template, check you've set up all the requirements (BBDD, config files,..) and try to access to `APP_PATH/frontend/web`

Installation guide: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md

Comment: when i try to access to APP_PATH/frontend/web, i have a server 500 error, same problem if i delete .htacess